# Want to figure out what it wrong with my fraction to decimal converter in java

Tags: java, methods

I am doing a project for class and I just wanted to find out what is wrong with my converter from fractions to decimal values? And it has to be done with methods.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fraction
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

        int numerator, int denominator, result;
        System.out.println ( "Please enter the numerator: " );
        num = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println ( "Please enter the denominator: " );
        den = input.nextInt();
        result = double(numerator/denominator);
    }

    public static int double( int x )
    {
        if (denominator == 0){
            System.out.println ( "Can't divide by zero" );
        }
        else {
            double fraction = (double)numerator / denominator;
            System.out.println(fraction);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the result you're getting? What is the expected result?

Comment: I want for the user to input the numerator, then the denominator. and then create doubles out of those numbers and calculate the decimal of that fraction

Comment: I'm guessing it doesn't compile, since numerator and denominator are local to main and not parameters.

Comment: You may want to read a basic tutorial. double is a reserved keyword. The scopes of numerator and denominator are local to the main, you can't access them in your "double" method. You need to return something from your method, it's not the case here.

Comment: Your using "double" as the method name. Its a reserved keyword and cant be used like that. Just change the name of the method.

Comment: Also, you should not name a method `double` since that's the name of the Java type.

Comment: so how to i make the numerator and denominator doubles without putting it where i put it?\

Comment: And if denominator is zero you'll never even make the call, since the divide operation that calculates the parameter will throw a DivideByZeroError.

Comment: i Guess im just not understanding what to do, could someone show me with my code how to change it?

Comment: Thank you! this helped me a lot, i think i finally understand how to use methods now!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    int num, den;
    System.out.println ( "Please enter the numerator: " );
    num = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println ( "Please enter the denominator: " );
    den = input.nextInt();
    if (den != 0 ){
    System.out.println ("Decimal is " + convert (num, den));
    }
    else 
    System.out.println ("Cant divide by zero");       

}

public static double convert(int x, int y)
{        
        return ((double)x/y);        
}
```

Comment: Okay, so it worked but there is one problem. For the assignment they gave me two fraction to try once i finshed the program. i tried numerator of 2, denominator of 5. the paper i have says m result should be 0.400000 but it came up as only 0.4. also with the fraction 2/3 instead of giving me 0.666667 it gave me 0.666666666

Comment: is there anything i have to change to get those answers insteead of the ones i got

Comment: and i didnt downvote this, this code actually worked for me except for the answers not being the exact same

Comment: Thank you! this helped me a lot, i think i finally understand how to use methods now!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class Fraction  {
          method();

        }
    public void method () {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter the numerator: ");
            double numerator = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter the Denominator: ");
            double denominator = sc.nextInt();
            if (denominator == 0) {
                System.out.println("Can't divide by zero");
            }
            else {
                double fraction = (double)numerator / denominator;
                System.out.println(fraction);
            }
    }
```

Try this, instead of your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fraction
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

        int numerator, int denominator, result;
        System.out.println ( "Please enter the numerator: " );
        num = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println ( "Please enter the denominator: " );
        den = input.nextInt();
        result = double(numerator/denominator);
    }

    public static int doublenumber( int x ) // you can't use double only because it is reserved word in java.
    {
        if (denominator == 0){
            System.out.println ( "Can't divide by zero" );
        }
        else {
            double fraction = (double)numerator / denominator;
            System.out.println(fraction);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem with that is i need to be using methods for this assignment. and use doubles

Comment: easy, just put all that in a method and call the method., hold on 2 secs i update the answer.

Comment: sorry about the formatting, not at front of a computer, so can't really test / format correctly. but try this and let me know if it works.

Comment: Look at my answer. It does want you want using a method.

Comment: this didnt compile it had a problem with what the result equalled and the int denominator up top

Comment: Thank you! this helped me a lot, i think i finally understand how to use methods now!